# validation: date today in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with the today date. I have 2 checkings.

-The first validation is to avoid that the user enters a previous date to the today date. (my validation is ok)

-My second validation is to limit the dates to 2 years maximum (my validation is ok also)

My problem is that if I enter the today date, I get an error message. Normally, my date must be ok.

I think my problem is here?

```
const inputDate = new Date(date_start);
const today = new Date();

if (inputDate < today) {
    document.getElementById('date_startError').innerHTML = " ** Obsolete date ! ";
    return false;
}
```

Thank you for your help and your time.

```js
function validation()
{
    const date_start = document.getElementById('date_start').value;


    if(!date_start){
        document.getElementById('date_startError').innerHTML = " ** Empty ! ";
        return false;
    }
    
    const inputDate = new Date(date_start);
    const today = new Date();

    if (inputDate < today) {
        document.getElementById('date_startError').innerHTML = " ** Obsolete date ! ";
        return false;
    }

    const yearFromImputDate = inputDate.getFullYear();
    
    const now = new Date();
    const twoYearsFromNow = now.getFullYear() + 2;

    if(yearFromImputDate > twoYearsFromNow) {
        document.getElementById('date_startError').innerHTML = " ** Maximum 2 years ! ";
        return false;
    }



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titre de la page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" onsubmit="return validation()" >
  <br>
  <label>Date start : </label>
  <br>
  <input type="date" name="date_start" id="date_start" placeholder="2020-05-28">
  <br>
  <span id="date_startError"></span>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I selected today's date and form got submitted.

Comment: @Rayon: We are on `02-06-2020` I have an error message.

Comment: Got your point.

Comment: Your 2 year check is wrong unless the date is allowed to be any month in 2022 which is what you are checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take off the timezone using Date.UTC() and set hours, minutes and seconds to zero.

By the way, add 2 years from `today` to compare max date, instead of only year.

```js
function validation()
{
    const date_start = document.getElementById('date_start').value;


    if(!date_start){
        document.getElementById('date_startError').innerHTML = " ** Empty ! ";
        return false;
    }
    
    const inputDate = new Date(date_start);
    const today = new Date(Date.UTC(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate(), 0,0,0,0));

    if (inputDate < today) {
        console.log(inputDate, today);
        document.getElementById('date_startError').innerHTML = " ** Obsolete date ! ";
        return false;
    }

    const twoYearsFromNow = new Date(today);
    twoYearsFromNow.setYear(today.getFullYear() + 2);

    if(inputDate > twoYearsFromNow) {
        document.getElementById('date_startError').innerHTML = " ** Maximum 2 years ! ";
        return false;
    }

    console.log(inputDate, today, twoYearsFromNow);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titre de la page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" onsubmit="return validation()" >
  <br>
  <label>Date start : </label>
  <br>
  <input type="date" name="date_start" id="date_start" placeholder="2020-05-28">
  <br>
  <span id="date_startError"></span>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Triby, I understood, thank you alot for your help/time.

Answer (score 0):

you have that ** Obsolete date ! on today's date because inputDate is in UTC and your today is in local time hence why it will trigger the error message to fix this 
convert Local time to UTC or vice versa 
or set hours minutes and seconds to 0 for both and then compare them

```
    today= new Date()
        const myToday = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 
        today.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);

    //OR use getTimezoneOffset it will return the difference from UTC and your local time
    currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60  
    let offset= currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours*3600000
 // and then remove offset from your local time 
     today= Date.now 
     let localtimeinUTC=today-offset
//and then you compare the time  localtimeinUTC with your inputTime
```

but i suggest you use the first approach as it simpler

Comment: Or If you are not concerned about time, set Hours/minutes/seconds to 0 before comparison.

Comment: @Sven.hig: Thank you Sven.hig  but, what should i change? I am beginner... :-(